# Proving that $A$ is countably infinite from another statement

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to learn Real Analysis from lectures available online: [Mathematics-Real Analysis(nptel)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=md5UCR7mcIY&list=PLbMVogVj5nJSxFihV-ec4A3z_FOGPRCo-)

The professor tries to prove that (3) implies (1) in the following (in his [4th Lecture of 1st module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xx7ULr79fy0&list=PLbMVogVj5nJSxFihV-ec4A3z_FOGPRCo-&index=4)):

1. $A$ is countably infinite,
2. $\exists$ a subset $B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ and a map $f:B \to A$ that is onto,
3. $\exists$ a subset $C$ of $\mathbb{N}$ and a map $g:A \to C$ that is one-one.

**Proof:** (At 22:00 of the above video)

Consider the map $A\to g(A)$

Now, this is onto and hence, $A\approx g(A)$

also, it is clear that $g(A)\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and we know that every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable hence, g(A) is countable and particularly countably infinite

therefore, $A$ is countably infinite

**My Doubt:** why $g(A)$ is countably infinite ?

Comment: Perhaps $A$ is already assumed to be infinite.  Failing that, the implication is false.

Answer (score 0):

3) implies 1) is false. $C$ and $A$ could both have one element each in which case there is a one-to one map from $A$ to $C$.

Comment: have you seen the video I have mentioned, because in that the professor seems to claim this; might be I have interpreted something incorrectly, so please have a look at it